# Can someone please create a new "LEMP" stack tag on ServerFault?

Tags: discussion, tags

I hope I'm doing this right, I don't have enough reputation yet to create tags. It looks like the LAMP stack tag already exists, but the corresponding LEMP tag for Nginx (not Apache) server stacks does not yet exist here...

If you think this is a good idea and can create the tag, awesome!

Answer (score 4):

Going over the questions recently tagged [lamp](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/lamp), I've got to say I can't see that it adds any value.  As such, I'm having trouble imagining how a "lemp" tag is going to fare any better.  Can you provide (as an edit to your question) example tag wiki text which would explain when the use of the tag is appropriate and valuable?